# How to apply JavaScript to HTML table by class to show 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, html

How to apply JavaScript functions to HTML table by class to show 2 decimal places? The JavaScript
has to be applied onto a specific HTML table class "sal".

The table by default will have data from other sources in 4 5 or 6 decimal places which I need to output as 2 decimal places.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
           var num = document.getElementById("sal"); 
           var n = num.toFixed(2); 
           document.getElementById("sal") = n;
          }
         
         onload = myFunction()
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table class="tg" border=2px;>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th class="tg-hdr1">NAME</th>
            <th class="tg-hdr2">SALARY</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="tg-namehead">Andrew</td>
            <td class="tg-sal">211785.678489</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="tg-namehead">Pete</td>
            <td class="tg-sal">525225.7789</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="tg-namehead">Jack</td>
            <td class="tg-sal">98958.489</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select a documents' elements by class name using `document.getElementsByClassName(className)`.

```
var salaries = document.getElementsByClassName("tg-sal");
for (i = 0; i < salaries.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = salaries[i].innerHTML;
    var newValue = currentValue.substring(0, currentValue.indexOf(".") + 2);
    salaries[i].innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Working fine but one problem is there.
in my table I am getting unorganized format.
like I need data as 0.35% whereas it's showing .35%

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using [`Number.prototype.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tg-sal').forEach((e)=>{
  e.innerText = Number(e.innerText).toFixed(2);
})
```

```html
<table class="tg" border=2px;>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-hdr1">NAME</th>
      <th class="tg-hdr2">SALARY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-namehead">Andrew</td>
      <td class="tg-sal">211785.678489</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-namehead">Pete</td>
      <td class="tg-sal">525225.7789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-namehead">Jack</td>
      <td class="tg-sal">98958.489</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```